# Can JBoss Seam disrupt JSF life cycle?

Tags: jsf, jboss-seam

I used jboss seam in my jsf application because of conversation scope and bijection features. But I worry about jboss seam disrupt jsf life cycle. Can jboss seam interrupt jsf life cycle?

Comment: Interrupt like...? I mean, Seam has interceptors and the likes, but AFAIK it doesn't break the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple answer to this question.  I think you should look at chapter 3 of [Seam in Action](http://www.manning.com/dallen/) by Dan Allen for a detailed overview of how Seam (2.x) extends the JSF (1.2) life-cycle using servlet filters and a JSF phase listener.  References are provided to classes in the Seam implementation (specific servlet filters, phase listener) that would make it easy to jump into the source code.  There is also a diagram that compares HTTP request handling with and without Seam added to JSF.  A less detailed description of Seam's request handling by the same author can be found [here in the *Seam and JSF* section](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-seam1/).